# RecyclerView - How to smooth scroll to top of item on a certain position inside Nested scrollview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview, nestedscrollview

I implemented Recycler view, when click on recyclerview it goes to next activity but when I came back I should be back with the same position which I was clicked, like I need to scroll to specific position based on the position of the item, I have the position but I couldn't able to scroll because of nested scrollview.

How can I fix this issue?

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"

        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/theme_color"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
            app:title="@string/app_name"

            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_report_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:orientation="vertical">
......

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/theme_color"
                app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    >
.....
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/palegray"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:id="@+id/nested_scroll"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/palegray"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/card_header" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In this recyclerview, I need to scroll to specific item based on the position how can I make it? I used:

```
            recyclerview.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
```

But didn't worked, and I used this one also but this one also dint worked for me,

```
RecyclerView.SmoothScroller smoothScroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(RoleActivity.this) {
                            @Override protected int getVerticalSnapPreference() {
                                return LinearSmoothScroller.SNAP_TO_START;
                            }
                        };
                        smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(i);
                        mLayoutManager.startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private int mPosition = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
```

mPosition is the certain position you want to scroll. Save this in onSaveInstanceState

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
   outState.putInt(SELECTED_KEY, mPosition);
}
```

in onCreate

```
if(savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(SELECTED_KEY))
{
    mPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(SELECTED_KEY);
}
```

Call `mRecylerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mPosition)` once the data to be passed to reccylerview is ready,that is after adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: not working at all i need it to be sorted out for a recyclerview which is inside the Nested Scrollview ;(